# Add CGI-BIN to Tomcat 7 on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, proxy, cgi, cgi-bin

I am trying to use OpenLayers WPS Client which requires the usage of a CGI Proxy but I am unsure how to enable CGI on my Java EE web application.

I am aware that I must configure Tomcat to allow the usage of the WEB-INF/cgi folder but I am unsure how.

I am using Eclipse Juno for Java EE with the Tomcat 7 plugin thingy under Windows Server 2008 RC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading the [Tomcat CGI documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cgi-howto.html) which tells you how to enable CGI.

Comment: I had run the tutorial you mentioned with no success. Further Google searches showed me how dumb I was for using the wrong URL. I should be using the localhost:8080/appname/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi and was using the localhost:8080/appname/WEB-INF/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi instead. Dumb me. Thanks for helping anyway. I would upvote you but apparently I need more rep.